# context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

I have an `itemClickListener`in recycler view from which I want to see the exercise page.

Here is my code ;

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.image.setImageResource(exerciseList.get(position).getImage_id());
    holder.text.setText(exerciseList.get(position).getName());

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewExercise.class);
            intent.putExtra("image_id", exerciseList.get(position).getImage_id());
            intent.putExtra("name", exerciseList.get(position).getName());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

However, it says that context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

Could you help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addFlags` method inside `Intent` class like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewExercise.class);
intent.putExtra("image_id", exerciseList.get(position).getImage_id());
intent.putExtra("name", exerciseList.get(position).getName());
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this error when the `context` variable you use is not an `Activity` (i.e., you've used `getApplicationContext()`.

If you're starting an Activity from within an Activity (as you would with a `RecyclerView` click, you should be using the Activity as your context, either by using `this`, `YourActivityClass.this`, or even just using the context attached to your view via `view.getContext()` rather than the application context.